# Launch AlertDialog not from an Activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to launch an alert dialog when not in a class that extends activity, but I am on the GUI thread. I have access to my applications context and attempt to launch the alert dialog with that but get an error:

> 02-12 00:48:07.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1322): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong on this one?

Comment: is that the whole thing, or is there a stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot launch a dialog except via an activity, sorry.

You are welcome to create an activity that uses `Theme.Dialog` or something to look a bit like a dialog, if you wish.

Comment: So I know you can launch a Toast via the application context. How can I determine which things must be only launched via an activities context vs which ones will also work via the application context. Is there somewhere buried in the documentation that describes this? Thanks again

Comment: @metalideath: `Toasts` work. `startActivity()` works. Dialogs can only be opened from an activity. You determine this by searching StackOverflow or trial-and-error -- stuff like this tends not to be covered in the documentation, since there's no obvious spot for it.

Comment: So just to sum things up in case someone else has the same question. You cannot launch a dialog from the application's context but can launch it from the Activities context. If want a similar looking effect to a dialog then you can create an activity that uses the dialog theme and launch that with startActivity using the applications context.