# Application Crashes while Provider Disable in Locaton Manager

Tags: android, gps

I a new in android i want to find out the gps location and saving them in sqlite database periodically every thing is fine . I want that when gps is enabled it send location to the data base and when disable it show an alert dialog for settings. but in this case when I disable the gps it stopped working it gives an fatal exception .Any help in this will be appreciated.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

        private final Context mContext;


        // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean canGetLocation = false;
        boolean locarion =false;


        Location location; // location
        double latitude; // latitude
        double longitude; // longitude


        // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

        // Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;
        NotificationManager nm;
        Notification notification;

        public GPSTracker(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();

        }





        public Location getLocation() {

            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                         if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");






                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }



        /**
         * Stop using GPS listener
         * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
         * */
        public void stopUsingGPS(){
            if(locationManager != null){
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }       
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude(){
            if(location != null){
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude(){
            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }



        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         * @return boolean
         * */
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog
         * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
         * */


         public void showSettingsAlert(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }


         @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Log.d("Provider Disable", "Provider Diasble");

            showSettingsAlert();



        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Enabled ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Provider Enable", "Provider Enable");


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            //Log.d("Status changed", "status changed");

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Here is my log

```
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4053e520 is not valid; is your activity running?
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at com.example.gps.GPSTracker.showSettingsAlert(GPSTracker.java:212)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at com.example.gps.GPSTracker.onProviderDisabled(GPSTracker.java:242)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:240)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-09 01:01:10.188: E/AndroidRuntime(13936):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to show a dialog window using the activity you passed into your GPS tracker as its context but the activity is no longer available therefore you get the error message telling you context is invalid.

You may want to launch an activity instead and style it to look like a dialog.

[Launch AlertDialog not from an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977002/launch-alertdialog-not-from-an-activity)

Comment: Only launch an alertdialog that has a valid activity to attach to.

Comment: Can you modify the code this will help me a lot to under stand